# Django: DoesNotExist at /admin

Tags: python, django

I've a view that receives an argument to make a Query filter and show some results.

The URL for this view is:

**views.ProdCatDetail**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.allCat, name = 'allCat'),
    path('<slug:c_slug>', views.ProdCatDetail, name = 'ProdCatDetail'),
]
```

the problem is that if I want to access the admin panel, through:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin
```

I cannot becuase the view:

```
views.ProdCatDetail
```

gets called, and since there is no Category "admin" I get an error:

```
DoesNotExist at /admin
Category matching query does not exist.
```

How can avoid this, without using another URL for the ***views.ProdCatDetail*** view???

**UPDATE 1:**

This view filter the category model, and filters the product model to get all products corresponding to this category.

As you can see in the URL it accepts 1 parameter, that is: `<slug:c_slug>`, however, admin from `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin` is considered as a slug, when it shouldn't because I only this this URI to enter the admin panel.

I've tried using and if stament to control this flow:

```
if c_slug is not "muestras" and not "admin"
```

But now I'm getting:

***UnboundLocalError at /admin
local variable 'category' referenced before assignment***

```
def ProdCatDetail(request, c_slug):

    if c_slug is not "muestras" and not "admin":

        try:
            category = Category.objects.get(slug=c_slug)
            products = Product.objects.filter(category__slug=c_slug)
        except Exception as e:
            raise e

    return render(request, 'shop/productos_por_categoria.html', {'category': 
    category, 'products': products})
```

Comment: Why is this view called in the first place? Please provide more details

Comment: Please, see my update.

Comment: This is because you also call `render(..)` with `category` if the condition in the `if` is `False`. In that case you can not render the template with this context.

Comment: yes, but how can I do this: `if URI is admin just enter the admin panel` without affecting this view if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you might fix this with adding explicit path for `AdminSite` in your URLconf.
Try to add the following line **above** the path that has `views.ProdCatDetail` view.

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

However keep in mind that you should add admin package with:

```
from django.contrib import admin
```